# Syntax error in grub config file

Tags: grub2

I messed with the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` and now when I run `sudo update-grub` I get this:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober: 66: /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober: Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Please help! If you can give you me the same file to compare and see what is different.
Or give me a different solution. Boot repair doesn't work! It has the same problem!

Here is my file:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
set -e

# grub-mkconfig helper script.
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007,2008,2009  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="${prefix}"
datarootdir="${prefix}/share"

. "${datarootdir}/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib"

found_other_os=

make_timeout () { 
   if [ "x${found_other_os}" = "x" ] ; then 
     if [ "x${1}" != "x" ] ; then 
      if [ "x${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET}" = "xtrue" ] ; then 
    verbose= 
      else 
    verbose=" --verbose" 
      fi 

      if [ "x${1}" = "x0" ] ; then 
    cat <<EOF 
if [ "x\${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then 
  if keystatus; then 
    if keystatus --shift; then 
      set timeout=-1 
    else 
      set timeout=0 
    fi 
  else 
    if sleep$verbose --interruptible 3 ; then 
      set timeout=0 
    fi 
  fi 
fi 
EOF 
      else 
    cat << EOF 
if [ "x\${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then 
  if sleep$verbose --interruptible ${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT} ; then 
    set timeout=0 
  fi 
fi 
EOF 
      fi 
    fi 
  fi 
}
EOF
}

adjust_timeout () {
  if [ "x$GRUB_BUTTON_CMOS_ADDRESS" != "x" ]; then
    cat <<EOF
if cmostest $GRUB_BUTTON_CMOS_ADDRESS ; then
EOF
    make_timeout "${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_BUTTON}" "${GRUB_TIMEOUT_BUTTON}"
    echo else
    make_timeout "${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT}" "${GRUB_TIMEOUT}"
    echo fi
  else
    make_timeout "${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT}" "${GRUB_TIMEOUT}"
  fi
}

if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER}" = "xtrue" ]; then
  adjust_timeout
  exit 0
fi

if [ -z "`which os-prober 2> /dev/null`" -o -z "`which linux-boot-prober 2> /dev/null`" ] ; then
  # missing os-prober and/or linux-boot-prober
  adjust_timeout
  exit 0
fi

OSPROBED="`os-prober | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
if [ -z "${OSPROBED}" ] ; then
  # empty os-prober output, nothing doing
  adjust_timeout
  exit 0
fi

osx_entry() {
    found_other_os=1
        cat << EOF
menuentry "${LONGNAME} (${2}-bit) (on ${DEVICE})" --class osx --class darwin --class os {
EOF
    save_default_entry | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
    prepare_grub_to_access_device ${DEVICE} | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
    cat << EOF
        load_video
        set do_resume=0
        if [ /var/vm/sleepimage -nt10 / ]; then
           if xnu_resume /var/vm/sleepimage; then
             set do_resume=1
           fi
        fi
        if [ \$do_resume = 0 ]; then
           xnu_uuid ${OSXUUID} uuid
           if [ -f /Extra/DSDT.aml ]; then
              acpi -e /Extra/DSDT.aml
           fi
           $1 /mach_kernel boot-uuid=\${uuid} rd=*uuid
           if [ /System/Library/Extensions.mkext -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_mkext /System/Library/Extensions.mkext
           else
              xnu_kextdir /System/Library/Extensions
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/Extensions.mkext ]; then
              xnu_mkext /Extra/Extensions.mkext
           fi
           if [ -d /Extra/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kextdir /Extra/Extensions
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/devprop.bin ]; then
              xnu_devprop_load /Extra/devprop.bin
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.jpg ]; then
              insmod jpeg
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.jpg
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.png ]; then
              insmod png
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.png
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.tga ]; then
              insmod tga
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.tga
           fi
        fi
}
EOF
}

wubi=

for OS in ${OSPROBED} ; do
  DEVICE="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 1`"
  LONGNAME="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr '^' ' '`"
  LABEL="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 3 | tr '^' ' '`"
  BOOT="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 4`"

  if [ -z "${LONGNAME}" ] ; then
    LONGNAME="${LABEL}"
  fi

  echo "Found ${LONGNAME} on ${DEVICE}" >&2

  case ${BOOT} in
    chain)

      case ${LONGNAME} in
    Windows*)
      if [ -z "$wubi" ]; then
        if [ -x /usr/share/lupin-support/grub-mkimage ] && \
           /usr/share/lupin-support/grub-mkimage --test; then
          wubi=yes
        else
          wubi=no
        fi
      fi
      if [ "$wubi" = yes ]; then
        echo "Skipping ${LONGNAME} on Wubi system" >&2
        continue
      fi
      ;;
      esac

      found_other_os=1
      cat << EOF
menuentry "${LONGNAME} (on ${DEVICE})" --class windows --class os {
EOF
      save_default_entry | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
      prepare_grub_to_access_device ${DEVICE} | sed -e "s/^/\t/"

      case ${LONGNAME} in
    Windows\ Vista*|Windows\ 7*|Windows\ Server\ 2008*)
    ;;
    *)
      cat << EOF
    drivemap -s (hd0) \${root}
EOF
    ;;
      esac

      cat <<EOF
    chainloader +1
}
EOF
    ;;
    linux)
      LINUXPROBED="`linux-boot-prober ${DEVICE} 2> /dev/null | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
      prepare_boot_cache=

      for LINUX in ${LINUXPROBED} ; do
        LROOT="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 1`"
        LBOOT="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 2`"
        LLABEL="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 3 | tr '^' ' '`"
        LKERNEL="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 4`"
        LINITRD="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 5`"
        LPARAMS="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 6- | tr '^' ' '`"

        if [ -z "${LLABEL}" ] ; then
          LLABEL="${LONGNAME}"
        fi

    if [ "${LROOT}" != "${LBOOT}" ]; then
      LKERNEL="${LKERNEL#/boot}"
      LINITRD="${LINITRD#/boot}"
    fi

    if [ -z "${prepare_boot_cache}" ]; then
      prepare_boot_cache="$(prepare_grub_to_access_device ${LBOOT} | sed -e "s/^/\t/")"
      [ "${prepare_boot_cache}" ] || continue
    fi
    found_other_os=1
        cat << EOF
menuentry "${LLABEL} (on ${DEVICE})" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
EOF
    save_default_entry | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
    printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}"
    cat <<  EOF
    linux ${LKERNEL} ${LPARAMS}
EOF
        if [ -n "${LINITRD}" ] ; then
          cat << EOF
    initrd ${LINITRD}
EOF
        fi
        cat << EOF
}
EOF
      done
    ;;
    macosx)
      OSXUUID="`grub-probe --target=fs_uuid --device ${DEVICE} 2> /dev/null`"
      osx_entry xnu_kernel 32
      osx_entry xnu_kernel64 64
    ;;
    hurd)
      found_other_os=1
      cat << EOF
menuentry "${LONGNAME} (on ${DEVICE})" --class hurd --class gnu --class os {
EOF
      save_default_entry | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
      prepare_grub_to_access_device ${DEVICE} | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
      grub_device="`${grub_probe} --device ${DEVICE} --target=drive`"
      mach_device="`echo "${grub_device}" | sed -e 's/(\(hd.*\),msdos\(.*\))/\1s\2/'`"
      grub_fs="`${grub_probe} --device ${DEVICE} --target=fs`"
      case "${grub_fs}" in
    *fs)    hurd_fs="${grub_fs}" ;;
    *)  hurd_fs="${grub_fs}fs" ;;
      esac
      cat << EOF
    multiboot /boot/gnumach.gz root=device:${mach_device}
    module /hurd/${hurd_fs}.static ${hurd_fs} --readonly \\
            --multiboot-command-line='\${kernel-command-line}' \\
            --host-priv-port='\${host-port}' \\
            --device-master-port='\${device-port}' \\
            --exec-server-task='\${exec-task}' -T typed '\${root}' \\
            '\$(task-create)' '\$(task-resume)'
    module /lib/ld.so.1 exec /hurd/exec '\$(exec-task=task-create)'
}
EOF
    ;;
    *)
      echo "  ${LONGNAME} is not yet supported by grub-mkconfig." >&2
    ;;
  esac
done

adjust_timeout
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`? From the error message it appears that the problem is an easily fixable syntax error.

Comment: here is my pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5986850/

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your export should be in /etc/default/grub but in 40_custom or in the code itself. That is what is then throwing the error.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

This is editing the code, see this sub-section.
Editing /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
echo " set color_normal=cyan/black"

But this says it can command line or menu entry.

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands

14.3 The list of command-line and menu entry commands
See entry on export

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. But can you break that down. Because I am not exactly sure what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Quick test is just to remove the two export lines from /etc/default/grub and see it you still get error.

Comment: Yup! Still got the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

This error states that on line 66 of the file `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, there is a closed curly bracket`}` that has no open match.

Use a text editor to remove line 66 from your file.

It helps to use `vim` with highlighted and colorized syntax. Doing so not only makes it easy to find line 66 but the curly bracket is displayed as white and highlighted in red to indicate an error in the code because it has no match.